# Uri String not Caching in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Helo guys,

I am using following Code.

```
                String fileName = "image" + "_" + title.getText().toString()+"_" + val.toString(); 
                photo = this.createFile(fileName, ".jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
                uriOfPhoto = Uri.fromFile(photo);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CAMERA_SELECT);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("Error", "Can't create file to take picture!");
            displayAlert("Can't create file to take picture!","SDCard Error!");
        }
    }

    private File createFile(String part, String ext) throws Exception
    {
        File tempDir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/Images");
        if(!tempDir.exists())
        {
            tempDir.mkdir();
        }
        tempDir.canWrite();
        return new File(tempDir, part+ext);
    }
});
```

The `UriOfPhoto` is giving me `uriString` not chached in debug. It is not storing uri of the file.How can i resolve this issue.

```
authority   Uri$Part$EmptyPart  (id=830004244032)   
fragment    Uri$Part$EmptyPart  (id=830004245408)   
host    "NOT CACHED" (id=830003914304)  
path    Uri$PathPart  (id=830067926736) 
port    -2  
query   Uri$Part$EmptyPart  (id=830004245408)   
scheme  "file" (id=830002660688)    
ssp null    
uriString   "NOT CACHED" (id=830003914304)  
userInfo    null
```

Best Regards

Comment: do you need to store the captured image in your path that it or any thing else

Answer (score 0):

This isn't enough info. What action are you putting into the intent you send? Are you sure that createFile actually creates a file?

The error listing you give isn't very useful. Is it part of the listing of variable values from debug? If so, where are you in the code when you look at the values?

Comment: yes, it does create a new file.uriOfPhoto = Uri.fromFile(photo); is where i want to get the value of uri of that file photo but i get above

Answer (score 0):

```
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/Images" + fileName + ".jpg";
UriOfPhoto = Uri.parse(fileName);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,  UriOfPhoto);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CAMERA_SELECT);
```

also the is no need of creating file for store photo you need to just pass the uri where the photo must be as above the Android OS create a file as you were trying to do and stores the captured image in that uri.